# The Logic while using Android listView

Tags: android, listview

I'm new to Android and just want to ask a very basic programming logic.

I have a listview of 30 items. How to show details of each list item in a new activity?
Do I need to create 30 activities? What logic should I use?

Comment: You can use dialog to show info if it is not much lengthy. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one Activity which will hold the logic of how to view your item.

On your ListView you should implement an OnClickListener. Inside this OnClickListener you should pass the object which holds the selected item data to your details activity.

Check [Vogella Tutorial on ListViews](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: That was what I was looking for! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to create only one activity. Use intent or bundle to pass the data from list activity to new activity.